# Why is react native navigation very slow in a class component very very slow

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation, react-navigation-drawer

If i use class component to link my navigation, it will spend about 40 seconds before it switch to the screen.
**Why please?**

```
class NotificationScreen extends Component {
render() {
    return (
        <ApplicationProvider mapping={mapping} theme={theme}>
        <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
         <Button onPress={() => this.props.navigation.goBack()} title="Go back home">Go back</Button>
       </View>
     </ApplicationProvider>
    );
}
}
export default NotificationScreen;
```

Here's the navigation below

```
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

   class App extends Component {
 render(){
 return (
<>
{!AsyncStorage.getItem('@MySuperStore:key')?
<ApplicationProvider mapping={mapping} theme={theme}>
<NavigationContainer>
  <Drawer.Navigator drawerType="slide" initialRouteName="Home">
    <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={Dashboard}  />
    <Drawer.Screen name="Notifications" component= 
  {NotificationScreen} />
  </Drawer.Navigator>
  </NavigationContainer>

 </ApplicationProvider>
 :
  <AppNavigatorLanding />
```

}

Who have experienced this before?

Answer (score 0):

If you would provide a snack project, it would be more helpful to see the issue. Please see: https://snack.expo.io/